# What is the absolute path of BASE DIR?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, static

Django newbie here. I have trouble understanding the meaning of:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

and

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
)
```

What's happening here?

I take it the "**file**" is the settings.py file we are in (?), so the BASE_Dir is two folders up from that...? i.e. the one with manage.py in it?

So the STATIC_ROOT, will be one? or two? directories up from the BASE_DIR. Will the STATIC_ROOT FOLDER be made for me? Or do I have to make one called "static"?

```
└── MY_PROJECT
    ├── BASE_DIR
    │   ├── MY_APP
    │   │   └── settings.py
    │   └── manage.py
    └── static
```

Is the above right for this example? Then what the heck / where the heck will the STATIC_FILES_DIRS be?

Comment: Here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.dirname get the abs path of the base directory of the application. Rest i guess you can figure out.

Comment: thanks, and what do I do with `os.path.dirname(path)`?

Comment: It is getting the absolute path of the directory again, which I believe you already have in `BASE_DIR`

Comment: ok. err, thanks. Possibly stellar information, but way over my head.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to know where is located BASE_DIR, you can print it to the terminal, just add this line to your settings.py:

```
print "base dir path", BASE_DIR
```

and runserver to see results.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you django11. That would solve many of my problems.

Comment: In the current Django version, the command should be: 

print ("base dir path", PROJECT_ROOT)

Comment: @Dror Which version are you referring to ?? I just checked it in Django 1.10 and it is working fine.

Comment: @Cody the "print" command is python's.  I was using python 3.5.X

Answer (score 75):

BASE_DIR is your Django project directory. The same directory where manage.py is located.

Comment: short, simple and neat

Answer (score 25):

If your settings.py is configured like this, your filesystem looks like this:

```
└── MY_PROJECT
    ├── BASE_DIR
    │   ├── MY_APP
    │   │   └── settings.py
    │   └── manage.py
    └── static        -> STATIC_ROOT
        └── static    -> STATICFILES_DIRS
```

But it is not a good configuration because it mixes up collected statics and the directory where Django tries to find static files (e. g. to collect them). May be better to use this:

```
└── MY_PROJECT
    └── BASE_DIR
        ├── my_app
        │   ├── settings.py
        │   └── static              -> STATICFILES_DIRS
        ├── manage.py
        └── deployment
            ├── collected_static    -> STATIC_ROOT
            └── media               -> MEDIA_ROOT
```

---

```
# settings.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, "my_app", "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "deployment", "collected_static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "deployment", "media")
```

Now you can easily deploy your static and media files using your favorite webserver (Apache, Nginx etc.) pointing it to the "deployment" directory.

**Update:**

I added also a recommendable configuration for MEDIA_ROOT and changed the path for the collected static.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much Norman. May your loins be fruitfull.

Comment: That tree diagram was super useful!

Comment: should MEDIA_ROOT be under BASEDIR or under MY_APP ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer was written for Python 3 and Django 3.x.

It is common to set up a Django project for [`dev`, `prod` and perhaps `test` settings](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html). These settings usually inherit from `base` settings, which are defined in a file called `your_app_name/settings/base.py`. Within `base.py`, `BASE_DIR` might be defined like this:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
```

The `manage.py shell` subcommand accepts a line to be interpreted by using the `-c` option.
Here is a one-line solution that displays `BASE_DIR` for a Django app called `frobshop`:

```sh
$ ./manage.py shell -c 'from frobshop.settings import base; print(f"BASE_DIR={base.BASE_DIR}")'
BASE_DIR=/var/work/django/frobshop
```

I provide additional information in my [Django Notes blog page](https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/02/12/django-notes.html#base).

Answer (score 1):

for path settings in django projects i use

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_PRODUCTION_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'static_production'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_PRODUCTION_DIR, "static")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_PRODUCTION_DIR, "media")


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did and that really helped me was :

1. go to settings.py and add --> STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] at the end of file.
2. Go to the base html template in your templates folder, and add these 2 lines in the head section  (Just make sure you create a folder in static. in my case it is css as you can see below, could be different name ):

   a){% load static %}
   b)

Answer (score 0):

if anything contains path in it that you didn't understand where is it or how it works just type in the bottom of your file `print('my directory', UNKNOWN_DIR)` then run in Terminal `Python manage.py runserver`.

`'my directory'` is just a string you can type in any string then `UNKNOWN_DIR` is what you wanna know where is it. then run `Python manage.py runserver`.

EXEMPLES:

> print('my path', (os.path.abspath(**file**)) )

`python manage.py runserver`

> print('my path', (os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))) )

`python manage.py runserver`

> print('my path', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') )

`python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code below to **"settings.py"** so that you can see **the absolute path  of "BASE_DIR"** on your console:

```py
# "settings.py"

print("BASE_DIR is", BASE_DIR)
```