# Django Static Files - CSS File doesnt load

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django. I am trying to load a static css file, but it doesn't work.
That's part of my `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- css -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'HomePage/style.css' %}">


  </head>
```

and that's part of my `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
]
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")
```

Where did I make mistake ?

I have already used `python manage.py collectstatic` in command prompt

edit:
I see that I declareted STATICFILES_DIRS list two times.

Answer (score 1):

How does `href` look in the browser?

I would guess there is a missing `/` in the `href` path.

```py
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/HomePage/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: I added it and It didn't change anything

Comment: Can you show, how this line looks in the source of the browser? (In the browser: right click -> view page source)

Comment: ``` <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- css -->
   
  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/HomePage/style.css">

    
    <title>Results</title>


  </head>
```

Comment: So, in your project app folder, there is a folder `static/HomePage` which contains the file `style.css`?

Comment: yup, HomePage/static/HomePage/style.css

Comment: and how does your `BASE_DIR` definition looks like?

Comment: BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

Comment: I would print this `BASE_DIR` and would check if this is as expected.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25689922/13674581

Comment: base dir path E:\Python projects\DjangoProject\mysite

Comment: so the full path of `style.css` is `E:/Python projects/DjangoProject/mysite/HomePage/static/HomePage/style.css `

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a dot in the path.

like `./HomePage/style.css`

Comment: It also didnt help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is resolving correctly because your source has `href="/static/HomePage/style.css"`

What happens when you open `localhost:8000/static/HomePage/style.css` in your browser. Do you get a 404?

And, to be sure, what happens with `localhost:8000/HomePage/static/HomePage/style.css`