# Delete folder or directory using API (django)

Tags: python, django, linux, django-rest-framework

I have written down a Python script to delete or remove a folder from file directory.
The code is below:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
path = 'media/user110'

try:
    path = os.path.join(base_dir, path)
    shutil.rmtree(path)
    print("Deleted: " + path)
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
```

This worked. But it's not working in API using Django.

If I print `path` it shows `'/home/Desktop/my_project/media/user110/`

But when I want to do this in API using Django, using same code, and print `path` I got `/media/user110/` and it throw an Exception saying `this directory doesn't exist`

Now I want to delete or remove file directory using API. I want the solution.

BTW, I am using Linux, and my project will deploy in Linux server.

Comment: You need to use the `BASE_DIR` from settings. This is the standard way to use base directories correctly in Django: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25688132/8382028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple use the below code snippet to delete a folder.

```
import shutil
import os
from main_app.settings import BASE_DIR

# This is your folder path
file_location = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/user110')

# Here, lets delete the file
shutil.rmtree(file_location, ignore_errors = False)
# making ignore_errors = True will not raise a FileNotFoundError
```